# Displaying welcome message on Alpine Linux from Dockerfile

Tags: dockerfile, alpine-linux

I am using this *Dockerfile*

```bash
FROM alpine:latest

RUN apk update && \
    apk add --no-cache mc curl nano git 
RUN apk add nethack && \
    apk add figlet cmatrix lynx mutt sl cmus newsboat ranger alpine dialog elinks fortune && \
    apk add gnuplot inxi ncdu nyancat sc screen tree units w3m wget zsh
    
RUN addgroup -g 10000 teamX && \
    adduser -u 10000 -G teamX -s /bin/sh -D userX

COPY entrypoint.sh /
RUN chmod 777 /entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "-c", "source entrypoint.sh"]
```

with an help script *entrypoint.sh*, which contains info about all the Linux packages mentioned and installed in the Dockerfile. I just made it shorter.

```bash
#!/bin/sh
echo "WELCOME !!!"
echo "Installed user soft:"

echo "wget - A command-line program for downloading files from the internet"
echo "zhs"
echo "curl"
echo "git"
whoami
mc
```

I build it and run:

```bash
 # docker build -t textlinux -f Dockerfile .
 # docker run -it textlinux
```

It prints out the welcome info correctly, but does not recognize commands `whoami` and `mc`.
Then it halts the container and exits

```
curl
git
: not foundtrypoint.sh: line 31: whoami
: not foundtrypoint.sh: line 32: mc
: not foundtrypoint.sh: line 33:
```

I tried to move commands whoami and mc to Dockerfile, no effect

```bash
CMD ["whoami"]  
CMD ["mc"]
```

Removing the welcome script and only installing stuff and running mc makes alpine linux work correctly.

Comment: it seems to be working for me. I built it and it opened the MC expected. https://www.screencast.com/t/YpSnuymOW without the MC command: https://www.screencast.com/t/iLCigvsF 

About it being quiting after running the entry point this is expected since no other command has been assigned on the entry point script.

Comment: @FelipeEsteves and has it printed the welcome message with (partial) list of installed software?

Comment: it won't print the installed software. it will print the echo scripts in the entry point. Please check the screenshots I've added to my previous comment.

Comment: apk list would print all the installed packages. Is that what you want?

check that: $ docker run -it alpine apk list

Comment: I commented out the ENTRYPOINT line and 2 last lines are: CMD ["apk", "list']  and
CMD ["mc"].  As the result, it avoids printing packages, just runs mc

Comment: @FelipeEsteves but in general I don't want to print packages, as they contain version number and are not final command. I need a list of available commands, introduced with installed packages.

Comment: you can add a grep to your apk list to make the list shorter. Can I reply answer the question and then would you flag it as answered?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly? My wild guess is that you are trying to help users call (or recall) commends easily. Is it correct?

Comment: Also one thing: `mc` is going to take the whole screen, if I am not mistaken, so, what is the point to display an help prior to it?

Comment: This said, most of your issue is that you want to execute your entrypoint, not source it: `ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]`.

Comment: Benoit, this is mostly for fun/self-learning. Yes - I want to give info to the user. It does not matter MC covers the whole screen, when CRTL+O is available. Issue with this entrypoint.sh is that even though it's executable, I can only run it with source entrypoint.sh.  Anyway, I guess I found an answer (or rather a workaround)

Comment: _Issue with this entrypoint.sh is that even though it's executable, I can only run it with source entrypoint.sh_ > I cannot reproduce this. Are you running your container with a `USER` directive?

Comment: Benoit, no, just docker run -it textlinux. Anyway, python solved the whole issue (or allowed to walk around it) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved (worked around?) using a python script.

run.py:

```
import os

text_wall = ("WELCOME !!!", 
             "Installed user soft:", 
             "nethack - A classic roguelike game with procedurally generated dungeons", 
             "ranger", 
             "...... many other lines ...", 
             "curl", 
             "git")
             
for text in text_wall:
    print (text)

print("\nCURRENT USER: ")
os.system('whoami')
os.system('mc')
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:latest

RUN apk update && \
    apk add --no-cache mc curl nano git 
RUN apk add nethack && \
    apk add figlet cmatrix lynx mutt sl cmus newsboat ranger alpine dialog elinks fortune && \
    apk add gnuplot inxi ncdu nyancat sc screen tree units w3m wget zsh
    
RUN addgroup -g 10000 teamX && \
    adduser -u 10000 -G teamX -s /bin/sh -D userX

COPY run.py /

USER userX

CMD ["python", "run.py"]
```

If you have some other idea or comment on this solution, please share. I'll leave the question open for the next few days.

Answer (score 0):

I think that would help. I added the commands you'd like to make available to a variable and then printed them as a default output. Since grep would be too complex I think that isolating the commands and installing them would make more sense:

```
FROM alpine:latest

ENV INSTALL_PACKAGES 'cmatrix wget wget zsh'

RUN apk update && \
    apk add --no-cache mc curl nano git 
RUN apk add nethack && \
    apk add figlet lynx mutt sl cmus newsboat ranger alpine dialog elinks fortune && \
    apk add gnuplot inxi ncdu nyancat sc screen tree units w3m && \
    eval "apk add $INSTALL_PACKAGES"
    
RUN addgroup -g 10000 teamX && \
    adduser -u 10000 -G teamX -s /bin/sh -D userX

CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", "echo \"available commands: $INSTALL_PACKAGES\""]
```

Please let me know if that helps.

PS: every command on the Dockerfile generates a new layer. If you want just install the programs and they wouldn't change often I would recommend you to just group them on a single command in order to generate a single layer.

Comment: Thank you, but I actually need a list of commands: [alpine, cmatrix, wget] with short description, not package names like: qt6-qtwebsockets-dev-6.4.2-r0 x86_64 {qt6-qtwebsockets} (LGPL-2.1-only AND LGPL-3.0-only AND GPL-3.0-only AND Qt-GPL-exception-1.0). Such name does not tell anything :)
Even GREPing would not help here.

Comment: I am thinking about some workaround. Does AlpineLinux have something similar to Autostart folder in Windows, or autoexec.bat in DOS?

Comment: I did look for that listing /usr/bin but then a ton of programs would be listed. I also tried "man" command but again, you'd have to isolate the programs so I just added the programs to a variable instead. To install more programs ad add them the output just add them to the "INSTALL_PACKAGES" variable.